# Where is Android binary XML format documented?

Tags: android

This format is always trouble for reverse engeneering. When there are question about binary XML, the usual answer is "use apktool" (or something similar).

However, no tool is perfect; actually all suggested tools are more or less buggy, and I don't know tool that can successfully decompile and recompile **any APK** from Google Play.

Because such tools are usually open source ones, they are rarely updated and don't fix bugs for years (see **Issues** on github for any such tool and see how quickly issues are closed).

My question is: so, **where is this format documented?** If `apktool` and similar tools exists, it mean that they found format description somewhere and tried to implement its parser and writer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no actual documentation or specification. You pretty much just have to look at the source.

See, e.g.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/libs/androidfw/include/androidfw/ResourceTypes.h